# Event to capture deleting of a worksheet in a workbook

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm working on an Excel Add-in using the JavaScript APIs.

I need to capture the event in which:

1. A new worksheet is deleted from the workbook.
2. A new worksheet is added to the workbook.
3. A particular worksheet is selected in the workbook. [This works fine with `Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged`]

Need to know how to do this for 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't available from Office.js. You are only able to trap events for selection and data within a binding are changed.

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.